# Python Coding (call function / return values)

Tags: python, function, return, call

I am having trouble writing code for this question. I have seen this question asked in a few places but I still cannot figure out the answer from the tips they provided.

The question is: Write a program that has two functions: first() and second(). Function first() should print the string "In function first()" and then call function second(). Function second() should print the string "In function second(). In the global scopre, you should call function first().

This is the code I have..

```
def first():
    first = "In function first"


def second():
    second = "In function second"

print first(), second()
```

Does this look any closer? It still doesn't work but I put the print functions back in..

Comment: You are missing the part that says "and then call function `second()`".  Have you thought about how and where to do that?  Also, you can't use `return` outside a function.

Comment: You're also missing both the parts that say `print` the string...

Comment: I changed the cote a bit so that I had the print functions back in there. I took them out earlier and forgot to put them back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first = "In function first"` doesn't make the function return `"In function first"`.

I can understand why you might think otherwise. In some languages, the way to return a value is to assign it to the function. In other languages, assignment is an expression, and the last expression evaluated inside a function is the return value. So, there are a lot of languages where what you're doing would work.

But Python isn't one of them. In Python, the only way to return a value is with the `return` statement. And if you don't use a `return` statement, the caller just gets `None`.

So, your code just creates a local variable with (confusingly) the same name as the function, assigns a value to that, and then ignores that variable, so it ultimately has no effect.

What you want is:

```
def first():
    return "In function first"

def second():
    return "In function section"

print first(), second()
```

---

However, while that will give you the desired output, it isn't actually doing what you said you wanted:

> Function first() should print the string "In function first()"

In that case, it should have a `print` in it, not `return` a value that someone else has to print.

> … and then call function second().

Then you need to put the call to `second()` inside the definition of `first`, not outside of it.

> Function second() should print the string "In function second().

And again, it should `print`, not `return`.

So, this is a much better match to what you were trying to do:

```
def first():
    print "In function first"
    second()

def second():
    print "In function second"

first()
```

That being said, the code you wrote (with this fix) actually seems like *better* code than the code you wanted to write. Returning values from inner functions and handling output at the highest level is generally more flexible than having `print`s all over the place.

Comment: So I just needed to get rid of the = and change it to return. Thank you!

Comment: @Kayla, I wouldn't say that's "just" what you needed to do. You need to understand what's going on, and then you (still) need to follow the directions in the assignment.

Comment: @alexis, I understand that, I just didn't know what exactly I was doing wrong.